# Get List of Tabs which are visible to particular profile

Tags: apex, metadata-api, tooling-api, tab

We are modifying our project UI from scratch, and for that we are creating a new bootstrap NAVBAR. Salesforce Tabs are great and are profile based. What we want is feature of boostrap and feasibility of salesforce profile based tabs.( Make tab visible in profile setup and its done.)

How can i get list of tabs  which are visible to particular profile?

```
Schema.DescribeTabSetResult[] tabSetDesc = Schema.describeTabs();
```

provides us list of tabs that are App specific , what we want is to sort them wrt to profile.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Metadata API the [ProfileTabVisibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#profiletabvisibility_title) that is exposed via the Metadata API [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) will help you.

There is also [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_profile.htm?search_text=ProfileMetadata) in the Tooling API. This includes a Metadata field, that includes the same information as the Metadata API in the ProfileTabVisibility.